# Using Helvetica Neue in a Website

Tags: html, css, fonts

Normally, I use `"Helvetica Neue"` for the fonts in some websites although looking at other sites, I've seen some with `"HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue"`.

Is there any reason to reference Helvetica Neue in this way? Or should I stick with the normal that I use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are taking a 'shotgun' approach to referencing the font. The browser will attempt to match each font name with any installed fonts on the user's machine (in the order they have been listed).

In your example `"HelveticaNeue-Light"` will be tried first, if this font variant is unavailable the browser will try `"Helvetica Neue Light"` and finally `"Helvetica Neue"`.

As far as I'm aware `"Helvetica Neue"` isn't considered a 'web safe font', which means you won't be able to rely on it being installed for your entire user base. It is quite common to define `"serif"` or `"sans-serif"` as a final default position.

In order to use fonts which aren't 'web safe' you'll need to use a technique known as font embedding. Embedded fonts do not need to be installed on a user's computer, instead they are downloaded as part of the page. Be aware this increases the overall payload (just like an image does) and can have an impact on page load times.

A great resource for free fonts with open-source licenses is [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts). (You should still check individual licenses before using them.) Each font has a download link with instructions on how to embed them in your website.

Comment: Yeh, I don't think it is a web safe but it is a great font. Is there a place where you can download the web font and a @font-face kit? Or do you have to have a license?

Comment: Helvetica Neue isn't present in Linux or in Windows. The safest approach is to use a full stack: `font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`

Comment: @user1505209 Helvetica Neue is a font that would need to be licensed. Be aware that many of the 'web font' purchases come with restrictions on number of times a font can be 'viewed'. This can range on a month to month basis, or a total count. If you have a high traffic site, this can get exceptionally expensive: http://www.linotype.com/1266/NeueHelvetica-family.html?site=webfonts&format=ot-cff&branding=pro . If you want a free alternative though, you could try Liberation Sans: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/15464

Comment: In addition I want to mention that you can now use `@font-family` to include "custom" fonts.

Answer (score 41):

I'd recommend this article on CSS Tricks by Chris Coyier entitled Better Helvetica:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/better-helvetica/

He basically recommends the following declaration for covering all the bases:

```
body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: @BillyMoat, why some font names are in quotes and some are not ?? is that intended to be that way??

Comment: @Ĭsααctիεβöss That's only needed for the ones that have a space in them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have referenced and correctly integrated your font to your site (presumably using an @font-face kit) it should be alright to just reference yours the way you do. Presumably it is like this so they have fall backs incase some browsers do not render the fonts correctly

Comment: Well I haven't added Helvetica Neue as a @font-face kit. Would it be better if I did?

Comment: Yes you will need to, Helvetica won't be a web standard font, meaning it wont render for a lot of browsers. You should buy a licence for the font and generate an @font-face kit for it. Although some fonts have actually been restricted by their creator against being turned into web fonts

Comment: No one does that because of the price of web licence about $1k. It is better to use another font as fallback or completely different font. Unless you are working on a really big and worthy site.

Comment: Yea I know, it's ridiculous how expensive they are, especially if you aren't a business. I must have assumed from the question he was asking why is it quoting it, and writing it in that way, rather than what the fallbacks were