# Not all of the font weights are working (local font, Helvetica Neue) on my website

Tags: css

I have a Mac, which means I have Helvetica Neue preloaded locally. I can use it on website mockups I create, however 600 Italic and 300 Normal do not render on said websites, instead they simply render as 600 Normal and 200 Normal respectively.

I can use both of these font weights/styles just fine on Pages for example... Additionally, this happens on multiple Macs and multiple versions of OS X, so it seems like every single Mac in the world has this issue... It doesn't make sense, though, because ALL of the font variants are right there, 100, 200, 300, 400, etc...

Any ideas?

EDIT: I can get 300 Normal and 600 Italic to work if I use @font-face to point to a CSS file for a font I made up ("Duplicate Neue"), which in-turn points to the .woff files for Helvetica Neue's variants... Still, if the fonts are local, why won't they render!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it....

As per this thread- [Using Helvetica Neue in a Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070055/using-helvetica-neue-in-a-website#) - "Helvetica Neue" isn't going to cut it for font-family:.

To achieve certain font weights for the local font Helvetica Neue, one must use other font-family values, such as "HelveticaNeue-Thin" (200), etc. Font weight does not have to be defined for such font-families, since HelveticaNeue-Thin is of course only one font weight.

It should go without saying, but support for this font is very limited (it's preloaded on Apple devices only as far as I know), and for anyone who is insistent on using this font (like me), it is strongly suggested that you include backup fonts that will load on Windows, Android, Blackberry, Chrome OS, etc. devices.